# absolute positioned text area does not respect right and bottom properties

Tags: css, textarea

I am trying to absolute position a text area that will stretch to cover it's parent.
Unfortunately Chrome seems to ignore **right** property and Firefox ignores both **right** and **bottom** properties.

Here is the CSS I am using :

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#my-text-area {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

Here is a JsFiddle example :[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/mihai_coanda/csub6b96/)

Is there a **textarea** default property that i have to disable or are these just bugs?
There are workarounds to achieve the full width and height of the parent by inheriting these properties from the parent but i am looking for a way to make the absolute positioning for the scenario you would in the future have custom **right and bottom** not only **0**.

Comment: Just use top and left, then set height and width to 100%?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the textarea in an element and use same css on that element.
**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/csub6b96/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="my-text-area">

        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body,
html,
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
}

#my-text-area {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

textarea {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Reference: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/absolute-position-textarea

If you're interested in *why* this is required, it's because the browsers affected are those which render `textarea` as a *replaced element*. Rendering this control is delegated to the OS, and not handled by the browser itself, and it appears that certain CSS properties aren't respected when rendering a replaced element with `position: absolute`. The relevant (and complicated) section of the CSS spec is https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-replaced-width

Comment: This is a great workaround....i am still curious if there is a way to enable proper  behavior on the textarea itself.

Comment: @coandamihai I guess there is no way yet. The link which I shared describes about this behavior

Answer (score 0):

To achieve dynamic height and width from parent, you can use `inherit` keyword in `width, height` property in child.

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csub6b96/4/) to play.

```css
body,
html,
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
}

#my-text-area {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <textarea id="my-text-area"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: this works ...but if i would like in the future to modify the right or bottom properties to leave space for another element i would not be able to.

Comment: I don't get your point, where do you want to add another element?

Comment: For example yo have a 20px stripe element on the right of the textarea...if this positioning worked i would just have to modify the **right: 20px;** property and it would leave a space for the stripe but still resize accordingly to it's parent element.