# Why do right and bottom attributes not work an absolute positioned image?

Tags: css, absolute

I have noticed that I always need `height` & `width` attributes for absolute positioned images, even if I set `left`, `right`, `bottom` and `top` attributes.

See example code below or here: https://codepen.io/Rechi/pen/mdKQGym

The `div.descendant` follows the expected behavior, image does not.

Is the reason behind that the element replacement mentioned here:

- [absolute positioned text area does not respect right and bottom properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694110/absolute-positioned-text-area-does-not-respect-right-and-bottom-properties)?

```css
.ancestor {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.ancestor .descendant {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.ancestor img.descendant {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="ancestor">
  <div class="descendant"></div>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/17/47/test-pattern-152459_960_720.png" alt="" class="descendant">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your css classes without embedded.

Add space between composed classes as `img .descendant`.

```css
.ancestor {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.descendant {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

img .descendant {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="ancestor">
  <div class="descendant"></div>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/17/47/test-pattern-152459_960_720.png" alt="" class="descendant">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answere, unfortunatly I've copied my SASS-Code instead of the css result into my question. I tried to change my question but that did no longer work. But the problem is not the mentioned embedding.